How to place a label on top of 2 frames
How do I put a label on top of 2 frames? One frame is the background(wallpaper) and the other one is a box.

class HomeScreen(CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry('1700x720')

        # Define fonts
        self.font1 = CTkFont('Arial', 40, weight='bold')
        self.font9 = CTkFont('Arial', 15)

        self.wallpaper = CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color='#FFFFFF', border_color='#FFFFFF', width=10000, height=5000, border_width=4, corner_radius=20)
        self.wallpaper.pack(expand=True)
        self.frame = CTkFrame(self.wallpaper, fg_color='#ffffff', border_color='#efefef', width=525, height=220, border_width=4, corner_radius=20)
        self.frame.pack(expand=True)
        self.frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor='center')

        self.frameTitleLabel = CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Enter URL/Link", font=self.font9)
        self.frameTitleLabel.configure(text_color='white')
        self.frameTitleLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app = HomeScreen()
    main_app.mainloop()


I tried setting frame to wallpaper by dot notation but it didn't work. I don't know if this is possible.

Edited my  answer for a correction. Please see now.


How to place a label on top of 2 frames

How do I put a label on top of 2 frames? One frame is the background(wallpaper) and the other one is a box.


The problem can be fixed.
Move the CTkLabel widget to the top before self.wallpaper
Use pack() instead of place()
Snippet:
class HomeScreen(CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ...
       ...


        self.frameTitleLabel = CTkLabel(master=self, text="Enter URL/Link", font=self.font9)
        self.frameTitleLabel.configure(text_color='white')
        #self.frameTitleLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='n')
        self.frameTitleLabel.pack(side='top', anchor='n')


        self.wallpaper = CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color='#FFFFFF', border_color='#FFFFFF', width=500, height=500, border_width=4, corner_radius=20)
        self.wallpaper.pack(expand=True)

Screenshot:


You could put the label as a child of the main window.
Those are the changes:

Added a new label self.topLabel as a child of the main window (self).

Positioned the new label using place method with relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor='center'. This places it at the top center of the window.

Used self.font1 for the top label to make it larger and more visible.

Changed the text color of both labels to black for better visibility against the white background (Change it, in case you want a different design).
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry('1700x720')
        self.font1 = CTkFont('Arial', 40, weight='bold')
        self.font9 = CTkFont('Arial', 15)
        self.wallpaper = CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color='#FFFFFF', border_color='#FFFFFF', width=10000, height=5000, border_width=4, corner_radius=20)
        self.wallpaper.pack(expand=True)

        self.frame = CTkFrame(self.wallpaper, fg_color='#ffffff', border_color='#efefef', width=525, height=220, border_width=4, corner_radius=20)
        self.frame.pack(expand=True)
        self.frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor='center')

        # Create the label as a child of the main window (self)
        self.topLabel = CTkLabel(self, text="Top Label", font=self.font1)
        self.topLabel.configure(text_color='black')
        # Position the label on top of both frames
        self.topLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor='center')

        self.frameTitleLabel = CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Enter URL/Link", font=self.font9)
        self.frameTitleLabel.configure(text_color='black')  # Changed to black for visibility
        self.frameTitleLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')





You can't use both pack and place for a widget. You've used both pack and place for the widget self.frame

When you declare a widget(here Label), You don't need to provide the text or any other widget using Label.configure. Label.configure is useful when you want to change the value of the Label through a function. (Though your method works, this is not required). So I removed all the widget.configure()

As both the background and text are nearly the same color ('white'), the text is not visible. I changed to blue. Now it is visible.
from customtkinter import *
class HomeScreen(CTk):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.geometry('1700x720')

    # Define fonts
    self.font1 = CTkFont('Arial', 40, weight='bold')

    #Increased the font size for visibility. Change according to your requirement
    self.font9 = CTkFont('Arial', 40) 

    # Add the Label for the top text here
    lbl_1 = CTkLabel(master=self, text ='This is the top text', height = 30, font = self.font1, text_color = 'blue')

    lbl_1.pack(side = 'top', pady ='50')

    self.wallpaper = CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color='#FFFFFF', border_color='#FFFFFF', width=10000, height=5000, border_width=4, corner_radius=20)
    self.wallpaper.pack(expand=True)          


     self.frame = CTkFrame(self.wallpaper, fg_color='#ffffff', border_color='#efefef', width=525, height=220, border_width=4, corner_radius=20)
    self.frame.pack(side='top')
    # self.frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor='center')

    # Enter the text while declaring the widget. Text color I made into blue
    self.frameTitleLabel = CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Enter URL/Link", font=self.font9, text_color = 'blue')

    self.frameTitleLabel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app = HomeScreen()
    main_app.mainloop()





Edited my  answer for a correction. Please see now.
